# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Tags: python, api, flask, http-status-codes

I am getting the following error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

I am getting data through a API, and when the API is down the value is "down"

```
@app.route('/test_api')
def test_api():
    ipno = "192.168.0.120"
    port = "8060"

    url_time = 'https://{}:{}/time/'.format(ipno, port)
    url_member = 'https://{}:{}/member/'.format(ipno, port)
    url_state = 'https://{}:{}/state/'.format(ipno, port)

    if url_time.status_code == requests.codes.ok:

        r_time = _session.get(url_time).content
    else:
        r_time = "Time is down"

    if url_member.status_code == requests.codes.ok:

        r_member = _session.get(url_member).content
    else:
        r_member = "Member is down"

    if url_state.status_code == requests.codes.ok:

        r_state = _session.get(url_state).content
    else:
        r_state = "State is down"


    return render_template('test_api.html', time = json.loads(r_time), member=json.loads(r_member), state=json.loads(r_state))
```

Comment: As the error message tells you 'url_time' is a string. so it has not attribute 'status code' but you try to access that with 'url_time.status_code'. Next time add the full stack trace to your question. that makes it easier to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not making the actual request using the requests library:

```
url_time = 'https://{}:{}/time/'.format(ipno, port)
time_request = requests.get(url_time)
if time_request.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    r_time = _session.get(url_time).content
```

Comment: _session = requests.session()

Answer (score 0):

In the line `if url_time.status_code == requests.codes.ok:`:

`url_time` is a string, that is why you get the error. Strings dont have the attribute `status_code`.

Comment: what can i use in alternative to status_code or solve this issue ?

Comment: @ABU What do you want the `status_code` of `'https://192.168.0.120:8060/time/'` to be?

Comment: if the link is active then the data from the api else the API is down

Comment: @ABU Then you don't need an alternative to `status_code` but an alternative to the string. Strings know nothing about links or whether they are active or not. Did the answer by Joost not work?

Comment: Yess it did half work, the other problem its give is requests.exceptions.ConnectionError. which is because the API is off, or the server is off when this is the issue it should show off